# Book series where the main character is called "Priest". Mini-nukes used to rescue slaves

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a book series I started to read about five years ago and now I can't remember what it was called. It was set in space and on alien planets far in the future. All I can remember is these things: I think the main character was named "*Priest*", someone used mini-nukes as a weapon, and they were part of a group that rescued slaves.

Comment: With some changes in recollection, some of the Stainless Steel Rat series (Born/Drafted)? The prequels featured the Bishop, mini-nukes would be in keeping with the theme, and they do release slaves in a feudal setting in 'Drafted'...

Comment: Thanks @Michael but this doesn't seem to be it. The main character was named Bishop or Priest or something, not a side character.